# How do I prevent sed from endlessly reading stdin when run in eshell?

Tags: eshell

If you execute the following in bash:

```
$ echo hello | sed 's/hello/world/g'
world
```

sed quits immediately, as desired. If you do the same in eshell, sed will still print 'world' but it will keep running, reading from STDIN. Is there a workaround for this? I assume this happens because eshell isn't using normal pipes or something.

Comment: Ah, if I put a '*' before the echo it works like normal. It has something to do with the eshell builtin echo's behavior vs. regular echo.

Comment: Indeed. It's confusing the `echo` builtin is nowhere mentionned in eshell [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/Built_002dins.html#Built_002dins).